# Implied and Local Volatility relation in Monte Carlo

Tags: implied-volatility, monte-carlo, local-volatility, volatility-surface

I am implementing a Monte Carlo engine with the local volatility model based on Dupire.

Obviusly, I obtain the local volatility surface from the implied volatility surface and that surfaces has moneyness and expirys limits.
Imagine I have the volatility surfaces values between 0.6 and 1.5 in moneyness and from 0.1 to 2 years in time to expiration.

My question is, since I have to interpolate the local vol surface to know the instantaeous local vol value  on the Monte Carlo simulation ($\sigma(moneness, t))$, when I discretize the price equation (Euler) I will have to obtain $\frac{S_{t-1}}{S_{0}}$ between the moneyness values in each time step?

In this case, in each time pass the value of the moneyness would have to be between 0.6 and 1.5, which are the moneyness limits in the volatility surface.

Thanks

Comment: You can use extrapolation

Comment: Yes, I know, but my question is if those values that I obtain from the interpolation lead to moneyness value in that interval  (0.6, 1.5)  through all the simulation in each instant.

Comment: you extrapolate the volatility for moneyness < 0.6 or > 1.5

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that as I built that surface in that interval I would have to work always within it. Apart from that, my final goal is to calculate Vega with Autograd and it has several constraints about numpy and scipy so I have to do the inter/extra polation on my own. I was thinking in bilinear interpolation, what do you think?.

Comment: bilinear interpolation on the local volatility is fine as the model will remain arbitrage free. If you were to interpolate the implied volatility you would need something more involved.

Comment: Hi @AntoineConze is this no-arbitrage property of the bilinearly interpolated local vol surface documented somewhere ? Thanks for any pointers

Comment: There is no constraint on the local volatility for the model to be arbitrage free, so any interpolation scheme is fine.

Comment: As long as it is positive everywhere I, presume?

Comment: There is no constraint on local volatility being positive, because $+\sigma dW$ and $-\sigma dW$ are both gaussians with mean zero and standard deviation $|\sigma| \sqrt{dt}$. It is just a convention.

Comment: Sorry for asking again but, after doing a bilinear interpolation, which method should I use in order to extrapolate local volatility further than moneyness and expiration bounds (for t>v t1 and t>tn) where t1 and tn are the first and last expiration bounds on the surface. It would work making sigma(t, K)=sigma(t1, K) and sigma(tn, K) in the second case? Thanks again.

Comment: The simplest and most common extrapolation method is flat extrapolation, exactly as you suggest.